# Is it Possible to Keep Concurrent Package Versions in a Azure Build Pipeline?

Tags: npm, concurrency, package, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to create a versioning script in my Azure pipeline. I have spent more time than I care to mention working on it as this is my first time writing YAML/Powershell scripts. My end goal is to be able to have merges to main increment its minor and patch numbers depending on if it is coming from a release branch or a hotfix automatically. I am also incrementing the versions of alpha branches (feature), beta branches (release in testing), and rc branches (release candidates) based on pipeline runs of branches with the corresponding prefixes.

A brief example: You have a feature branch on 1.0.0-alpha.0, you manually build it and it goes to 1.0.0-alpha.1 if there are changes. You merge a rc into main and the mains version goes to 1.1.0 and the first published feature branch is 1.1.0-alpha.0.

My current issue is when I have multiple builds at once version conflicts occur. From my understanding this versioning scheme is fairly common but I haven't found a lot of information about automatically versioning through an azure build pipeline.

My current setup has a few stages.

1. There is a check for changes that stops the build if none are found to prevent unwanted increments from accidental builds (this in theory shouldn't happen but I am not the only developer working on this).
2. A version.json file is checked out from a branch titles version-control, this keeps a master record of each type of version (major,minor,patch,alpha,beta,hotfix,rc). This is then incremented based off of the branch being merged and merges into the main branch checks what branch the merged PR came from using azures rest api.
3. A version name is created with the numbers from this version.json file (input from stage 3) and stored as a artifact in a package.json file.
4. This stage builds and publishes the package.
5. If the publish stage was successful (no duplicate package versions) the updated version.json is pushed to the version-control branch and the updated package.json is pushed to the branch being built.

I am looking for a way to make sure there are no conflicts or at least they are dealt with when multiple builds run at once. I have not been able to find a good way to lock stages or even the whole build so they are sequential, in theory having queued builds would not be terrible as this should not have a ton of runs going through it.